# Scrapy Images Downloading

Tags: python, image, scrapy

My spider runs without displaying any errors but the images are not stored in the folder here are my scrapy files:

**Spider.py:**

```
import scrapy
import re
import os
import urlparse
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader.processors import Join, MapCompose, TakeFirst
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
from production.items import ProductionItem, ListResidentialItem

class productionSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "production"
    allowed_domains = ["someurl.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "someurl.com"
]

def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//html/body'):
        item = ProductionItem()
        img_url = sel.xpath('//a[@data-tealium-id="detail_nav_showphotos"]/@href').extract()[0]
        yield scrapy.Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, img_url),callback=self.parseBasicListingInfo,  meta={'item': item})

def parseBasicListingInfo(item, response):
    item = response.request.meta['item']
    item = ListResidentialItem()
    try:
        image_urls = map(unicode.strip,response.xpath('//a[@itemprop="contentUrl"]/@data-href').extract())
        item['image_urls'] = [ x for x in image_urls]
    except IndexError:
        item['image_urls'] = ''

    return item
```

**settings.py:**

```
from scrapy.settings.default_settings import ITEM_PIPELINES
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline

BOT_NAME = 'production'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['production.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'production.spiders'
DEFAULT_ITEM_CLASS = 'production.items'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
DEPTH_PRIORITY = 1
IMAGE_STORE = '/images'

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 250

DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline': 300,
}
```

**items.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class ProductionItem(scrapy.Item):
    img_url = scrapy.Field()

# ScrapingList Residential & Yield Estate for sale
class ListResidentialItem(scrapy.Item):
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()

    pass
```

My pipeline file is empty i'm not sure what i am suppose to add to the pipeline.py file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you don't know what to put in the pipelines I assume you can use the default pipeline for images provided by scrapy so in the `settings.py` file you can just declare it like

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline':1
}
```

Also, your images path is wrong the `/` means that you are going to the absolute root path of your machine, so you either put the absolute path to where you want to save or just do a relative path from where you are running your crawler

```
IMAGES_STORE = '/home/user/Documents/scrapy_project/images'
```

or

```
IMAGES_STORE = 'images'
```

Now, in the spider you extract the url but you don't save it into the item

```
item['image_urls'] = sel.xpath('//a[@data-tealium-id="detail_nav_showphotos"]/@href').extract_first()
```

The field has to literally be `image_urls` if you're using the default pipeline.

Now, in the `items.py` file you need to add the following 2 fields (both are required with this literal name)

```
image_urls=Field()
images=Field()
```

That should work

Comment: Thank you Rafael, however still no images populate the images folder, i added the pipeline to the settings.py file. changed the storage path and changed the following lines image_urls = map(unicode.strip,response.xpath('//a[@itemprop="contentUrl"]/@data-href').extract())
        item['image_urls'] = [ x for x in image_urls]

to item['image_urls'] = map(unicode.strip,response.xpath('//a[@itemprop="contentUrl"]/@data-href').extract())

Comment: You can't map the images, if you want to save multiple images in one item you have to make an array and not a map, that won't work

Comment: I'm fairly new to all of this, i tried fixing it by changing it to this ?
item['image_urls'] = response.xpath('//a[@itemprop="contentUrl"]/@data-href').extract()[0] the [0] should only give one image but it still doesn't show up am i still missing something or is it still an array ?

Comment: Instead of `return item` you should `yield item` just like requests

Comment: Sorry Rafael for consuming this much time, still not having luck with downloading the image. The folder still remains empty, no errors but shouldn't the image = scrapy.field() also be called somewhere in the code ?

Comment: No, that's only in the item class, by the way, in the `parseBasicListingInfo` function remove `item = ListResidentialItem()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120163/discussion-between-user1443063-and-rafael-almeida).

Answer (score 12):

My Working end result:

**spider.py**:

```
import scrapy
import re
import urlparse
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader.processors import Join, MapCompose, TakeFirst
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
from production.items import ProductionItem
from production.items import ImageItem

class productionSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "production"
    allowed_domains = ["url"]
    start_urls = [
        "startingurl.com"
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//html/body'):
        item = ProductionItem()
        img_url = sel.xpath('//a[@idd="followclaslink"]/@href').extract()[0]
        yield scrapy.Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, img_url),callback=self.parseImages,  meta={'item': item})

def parseImages(self, response):
    for elem in response.xpath("//img"):
        img_url = elem.xpath("@src").extract_first()
        yield ImageItem(image_urls=[img_url])
```

**Settings.py**

```
BOT_NAME = 'production'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['production.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'production.spiders'
DEFAULT_ITEM_CLASS = 'production.items'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
IMAGES_STORE = '/Users/home/images'

DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2

ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
```

**items.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class ProductionItem(scrapy.Item):
    img_url = scrapy.Field()
# ScrapingList Residential & Yield Estate for sale
class ListResidentialItem(scrapy.Item):
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()

class ImageItem(scrapy.Item):
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
```

**pipelines.py**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
        if not image_paths:
            raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
        item['image_paths'] = image_paths
        return item
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was the `IMAGES_STORE` path that was causing the problem

I did `IMAGES_STORE = 'images'` and it worked like a charm!

Here is complete code:

Settings:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'mutualartproject.pipelines.MyImagesPipeline': 1,
}

IMAGES_STORE = 'images'
```

Pipline:

```
class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
        if not image_paths:
            raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
        return item
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding my misstake here which threw me of for several hours. Perhaps it can help someone.

**From scrapy docs (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#using-the-images-pipeline):**

> Then, configure the target storage setting to a valid value that will be used for storing the downloaded images. **Otherwise the pipeline will remain disabled, even if you include it in the ITEM_PIPELINES setting.**

For some reason I used a colon ":" instead of an equal sign "=".

```
    # My misstake:
    IMAGES_STORE : '/Users/my_user/images'

    # Working code
    IMAGES_STORE = '/Users/my_user/images'
```

This dosen't return an error but instead leads to the pipeline not loading at all which for me was pretty hard to trouble shoot.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and nothing helped. After doing the following things started working:

```
pip install pillow
```

Comment: You will find the message `[scrapy.middleware] WARNING: Disabled scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline: ImagesPipeline requires installing Pillow 4.0.0 or later` in your scrapy log if you do not have pillow installed

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES and DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES  in the settings.py file