# Scrapy - Scrape both text and images in the same spider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Scrapy super noob here. Problem: I have an html page that contains both information that I want to scrape and an url that I want to follow to get images urls for images that I want to download and save via the scrapy image pipeline.

My approach to achieve this:
1. Scrape all the details as usual with a parse method
2. Find the url in the initial page, create a request that has a second parse method as callback where I build the image_urls list.

So, I have the following setup:

```
settings.py

...
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'crawlbot.pipelines.MybotPipeline': 300,
   'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1,
}

IMAGES_STORE = '/url/to/images' #valid path to actual folder
...
```

```
pipelines.py

import pymongo

class MybotPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
        db = self.conn['libraries']
        self.collection = db['books']

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.collection.insert(dict(item))
        return item
```

```
items.py

import scrapy

class MybotItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    description = scrapy.Field()
```

```
crawler.py

import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'myspider'
    allowed_domains = ['books.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.books.com/some/url'
        ]

        custom_settings = {
            'DEPTH_LIMIT': 1
        }

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_details(self, response):
        for image in enumerate(response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "jumbotron")]/div')):
            image_urls = image.xpath('div[contains(@class, "jumbotron-image")]/img/@src').getall()


    def parse_item(self, response):
        for idx, list_item in enumerate(response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "slider-wrapper")]')):
            anchor = list_item.xpath('div[contains(@class, "slider-section")]/div/a')
            slider_thumbnail = anchor.xpath('div[contains(@class, "slider-thumbnail")]')
            description = slider_thumbnail.xpath('div[contains(@class, "description-box")]')

            yield {
                'url': anchor.xpath('@href').get(),
                'description': description
            }

            details_page_urls = anchor.xpath('@href').getall()
            for details_page in details_page_urls:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=details_page, callback=self.parse_details)
```

This is not working, although with my little knowledge of both Scrapy and Python, the second parse method should return a list of image_urls. So I have 2 questions: 1. is there a better approach for my case? Maybe the whole issue is in trying to do too much with one spider? 2. If the approach is ok, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Look for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772662/scrapy-images-downloading

Comment: You simply assigning `image_urls` **variable** some value. For images pipeline you need to `yield` an item with `image_urls` field.